# Deploying react-boilerplate to Google Cloud Platform or Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering, next.js, react-boilerplate

Can anyone help me deploying react-boilerplate to Google Cloud Platform or Firebase Cloud functions. There are guides such as

Firebase
https://codeburst.io/next-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-with-firebase-hosting-7911465298f2
Cloud platform
https://medium.com/google-cloud/server-side-rendered-react-on-google-cloud-functions-8b51b2b0878c

These posts are for next.js not for react-boiler plate. Beginners like me have hard time customizing webpack config to work seamlessly with google cloud services.

Thanks

Comment: I have already searched for the solution for weeks but no luck at all... non of people have this requirement? ...weird enough...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on your end goal. But chances are you're personally looking for the firebase option.

Here is the relevant section from gcp docs

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#hosting_a_static_website_with_cloud_storage